# iOS Swift FCM not working without p12 file

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app with `Push Notification` capabilities. I've implemented a [RayWenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/20201639-firebase-cloud-messaging-for-ios-push-notifications) and some tutorials on the internet but I have a problem with the implementation and setting up `Firebase Console`. I've fully tested the applications with same code but it did not work. The tutorials all create a `p8 APNS Key` and upload it to FCM dashboard then there's no problem with that. But in my scenario, even code as same as the tutorial code, it won't work until I create & upload a new certificate for `Sandbox & Production` aka p12 file.

I've read the documentation of Firebase Cloud Messaging for iOS and there is just mention for p8 file creation aka APNS key. But I do not know why it not worked with p8 file and worked with p12 files? In another scenario it won't work and how the tutorial works without a `p12` upload? Is there any chance for the certification upload for FCM?

I can share the code but actually, it's %100 the same as the tutorial one.
Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "But I do not know why I have to upload the p12 file too?"  Says who!?

Comment: hey @ElTomato, I've read old-style documentation for push notifications and after trying it worked, I edited my question. Have you any suggestion why It did not work with p8 file?